# Confusion with word continue

Tags: grammar

Would you write:

> Did they continue seeing each other?

or

> Were they continue seeing each other?

Comment: You may not realise that English Language & Usage (EL&U) is a question and answer site for *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts*. There’s also [ell.se] where you might find some useful information and similar questions.. For further information about what's expected in a question on our EL&U site, see **[Ask]**.

Comment: *Each other* is spelled with a space in the middle of the two words.

Comment: @Chappo I dont know if youre the one who voted to migrate to ELL but it's my understanding they dont want questions that show zero research any more than ELU does.... See, eg, [this meta answer from an ELL mod](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3723/210913). (Although, in practice, ELL does not close many questions that show little or no research.)

Comment: @Knotell I flagged the post as showing insufficient research, but I'm aware that ELL takes the same approach, so no, I didn't flag for migration.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your sentence:

> they continued seeing each other.

You want to form a yes-no question. Here is the structure:

```
an auxiliary verb + subject + main verb
```

The main verb of your sentence is "continue". Since there is no auxiliary verb (like be, have, can or a modal verb) in your sentence, you should use **does** or **do** or **did**.

The tense of this sentence is *simple past*, so we choose **did** to form a yes-no question.

> Did they continue seeing each other?